# The highest direction of the trace operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, perturbation-theory

Let $W$ be a real and symmetric matrix $m \times m$ from the set $M_{m,m}$, and $T:M_{m,m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  a function defined by $T(W) = \operatorname{trace}(W^3)$.

We are interested to find the direction $V$ in $M_{m,m}$ such that, the directional derivative of $W$

\begin{equation}
\nabla T(W)_V = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {T(W+hV)-T(W)}{h}
\end{equation}

attains the maximum.

Intuitively, the direction $V$ must be to the 1-rank matrix $vv^T$, where $v$ is the eigenvector associated with the highest eigenvalue of $W$.

Is this intuition correct ? Even in the Hilbert spaces?

Comment: What is the set $\tilde{W_m}$?

Comment: The set of symmetric and real matrices (m x m).

Comment: You need to specify a matrix norm for $V$ to make this well-defined. The result is linear in $V$, so you need to be able to compare different "directions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $W\in S_m$, $DT_W:V\in S_m\rightarrow 3tr(W^2V)$. We may assume that $W^2=diag((\lambda_i)_i)$ where $\lambda_i\geq 0$. We consider the Frobenius inner product (cf. joriki post) $<A,B>=tr(A^TB)$. We seek $\sup_{||V||=1,V\in S_m}tr(W^2V)$. One has $tr(W^2V)=<W^2,V>=\sum_i\lambda_i v_{i,i}=\leq ||W^2||||V||=||W^2||=\sqrt{\sum_i\lambda_i^2}$.
We put $V=\dfrac{W^2}{||W^2||}$; then $||V||=1$ and $<W^2,V>=\sqrt{\sum_i\lambda_i^2}$, that is the required maximum.